# Mocking issue: Can not instantiate proxy of class. Could not find a parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to write unit test for a class which I can not change implementation.
Below is the error which I am seeing while writing tests.

**Unit to Mock:**

```
public class ClassA : IInterface
{
    public readonly ClassB _classB = null;

    public ClassA(ClassB classB)
    {
        _classB = classB;
    }

    private ClassP<ClassB, ClassC> _classP;

    public virtual ClassP<ClassB, ClassC> TargetToMock => _classP ?? (_classP = new ClassP<ClassB, ClassC>(_classB));
}
```

**Mocking:**

```
MockClassB = new Mock<ClassB>();

MockClassA = new Mock<ClassA>(MockClassB.Object);
```

**Setup:**

```
MockClassA
    .Setup(s => s.TargetToMock.SomeMethod(argument1, argument2))
    .Returns(SomeResponseObject);
```

**Exception:**

> Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can
>   not instantiate proxy of class: ClassP`2[[ClassB, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[ClassC, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
>   **Could not find a parameterless constructor.**

Comment: I think the correct way is `MockClassA = new ClassA(MockClassB.Object)`

Comment: you are right, actually I have a typo in the question